# Too many box2d objects makes my game slowly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I am writing a iOS game using Cocos2d. There are a lot of balls(about 7000 objects) in a screen.

When touch the screen, the balls should be exploded in the area, and it should be filled with around balls.

[image]

I created a box2d object for each of them and added it in the physics world.

Problems are as follows.

1. At first, when there is no touch event, screen is filled by 7000 balls, if we start the physics, they are overlapped each other, and there is a gap on top of the screen.

[image]

2. when touch the screen, the game works very slowly.

How can I make the game smoothly?

Comment: 7,000 balls. Each ball is contacting 6 other balls. Thats 42,000 points of contact. Each with its own force, momentum, etc... to calculate. Running at 60FPS (which you should be) you have 16 milliseconds to do everything for each frame. With the other stuff that's done (drawing etc...) it gives you maybe 4 or 5 milliseconds for the physics stuff. That's 95 nanoseconds per point of contact. It ain't gonna happen no matter what you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make the game smoothly?

Reduce the number of balls. 7000 physics enabled, colliding bodies is pure overkill. Even 700 is a lot.

In any case there's no quick fix for this. You can try to reduce the number of position & velocity iterations in the box2d world's timestep and do not use collision callback methods (don't set a collision delegate) but that's about it.

Comment: Then how can implement balls flows down effect?

Comment: Very broad question, but indeed it's often implemented with physics-enabled balls. However games like where's my water and feed me oil use far fewer balls, a custom renderer to combine multiple balls to look like larger splats of fluid and possibly even custom-made physics specifically made for this task. If you've seen the tech demos on PC there are fluid simulations (also lots of tiny balls) that run entirely on the GPU (graphics card) in order to achieve a half-decent framerate.

Comment: You may want to try reducing the velocity & position integration steps, that's about the only thing that may help improve performance. And in any case avoid implementing collision callbacks even if they run no code whatsoever the overhead of calling them will be noticable with 7000 balls.

Comment: Could you recommend any solution for implementing top 2 graphics?